# Unable to Obtain Template Column ComboBox Value in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I'm trying to obtain a cell value in a a DataGrid table, but am given an error after setting up the column as a TemplateColumn. Before, I had the column just as a ComboBoxColumn, and my code worked.

Here is my C# Code:

```
DataGridRow Row = (DataGridRow)MYGRID.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(MYGRID.SelectedIndex);
RowColumn = MYGRID.Columns[4].GetCellContent(Row).Parent as DataGridCell;
string Value = ((ComboBox)RowColumn.Content).Text;
```

Here is my XAML Code for the Column:

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ValueCol" Header="Value" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Options, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=UpdatedData, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" IsEditable="False" LostFocus="ComboBox_LostFocus"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

When updating the value, I get the following error:

```
'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox'.'
```

**EDIT**: Was able to obtain the new value by creating a LostFocus event and pulling the data from the RoutedEventArgs object.

Comment: Why are you mixing code-behind and binding?

Comment: may I know what is your requirement Chris? From your c# code, I can understand that, you are trying to get the text of the selected cell. Is it right?

Comment: @KevinCook I'm doing it this way because I'm raising other events on updates

Comment: @Karuppasamy I was actually able to obtain the value using a different method

Comment: @Chris, you are trying to cast the RowColumn.Content which is a content presenter to the comboBox, which might be the reason for the given error.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to obtain the new value by creating a LostFocus event and pulling the data from the RoutedEventArgs object.